# how to check server is running or not in Blazor webassembly for error handling

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http-headers, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor app and Just I want to know how we can check if the server is running or stopped to do better error handling

I'm using HttpClient PostAsJsonAsync for example for authnthication in Login and when the server is stopped I get an error

> "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

and

> "crit:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: TypeError: Failed to fetch System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: TypeError: Failed to fetch
> ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSException: TypeError: Failed to fetch    at
> System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    --- End of inner
> exception stack trace ---    at
> System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Toolbelt.Blazor.HttpClientInterceptorHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Toolbelt.Blazor.HttpClientInterceptorHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> System.Net.Http.HttpClient.g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage
> request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption,
> CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts,
> CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken
> originalCancellationToken)"

I have an Http Interceptor Service in my Blazor app and I want to check the connection before any action

Comment: Hi @Ali, Blazor WebAssembly is a client side app and how is your server side like? You can custom exception handler to check the error details in your server.

Comment: @rena my backend is asp core 6 and I need to check the connection because for example if I lose the connection with the server or lose the internet connection then I can't access the server side. in this case I have to let the user know about the issue